# wiimotelib bug?

Tags: c#, wiimote

I am recently writing a wiimote program:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using WiimoteLib;

namespace WiiTester
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Wiimote wm = new Wiimote();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


            wm.WiimoteChanged += wm_WiimoteChanged;
            wm.WiimoteExtensionChanged += wm_WiimoteExtensionChanged;

            wm.Connect();
            wm.SetReportType(InputReport.IRAccel, true);
        }

        void wm_WiimoteChanged(object sender, WiimoteChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            WiimoteState ws = args.WiimoteState;

            if (ws.ButtonState.A == true)
            {
                wm.SetRumble(true);
            }
            else
            {
                wm.SetRumble(false);
            }
        }

        void wm_WiimoteExtensionChanged(object sender, WiimoteExtensionChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            if (args.Inserted)
            {
                wm.SetReportType(InputReport.IRExtensionAccel, true);
            }
            else
            {
                wm.SetReportType(InputReport.IRAccel, true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My wiimote keeps getting disconnected and this error keeps running on wm.Connect();
Timed out waiting for status report

Is there a solution?

Comment: It seems that you're asking for this question like if Wii Mote PC support would be an officially supported approach. I believe you'll hardly get any support for that if you don't provide which unofficial library your code is using in order to work with a WiiMote!

Comment: I use the wiimotelib.dll library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a lot of experience with this library, and your problem is most likely being caused because you are calling SetRumble so often, this code:

```
    void wm_WiimoteChanged(object sender, WiimoteChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        WiimoteState ws = args.WiimoteState;

        if (ws.ButtonState.A == true)
        {
            wm.SetRumble(true);
        }
        else
        {
            wm.SetRumble(false);
        }
    }
```

Will call SetRumble constantly whether A is down or not, consider using this code instead:

```
    bool rumbleOn = false;

   void wm_WiimoteChanged(object sender, WiimoteChangedEventArgs args)
    {
      WiimoteState ws = args.WiimoteState;

      bool newRumble = (ws.ButtonState.A == true);

          if (rumbleOn != newRumble) 
      {
            rumbleOn = newRumble;
            wm.SetRumble(rumbleOn);
      }
    }
```

This way the set rumble method is only called when required and not constantly sending output reports to the WiiMote which causes the Bluetooth BUS to overload.